# Use ObservableCollection<T> as argument without specific type

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, observablecollection

Let's say we have two ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<Barcode> barcodeCollection; 
private ObservableCollection<User> userCollection;
```

I have two methods which will fill them with items from a database like this (I use a Backgroundworker):

```
 DispatcherObject.Invoke(
     new System.Action(() => BarcodeCollection.Add(new Barcode(dr))));
```

The rest of the methods are very repetitive and I thought I could capsulate some code in only one method and just pass the ObservableCollection like this:

```
    private void LoadCollection(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection)
    {

    }
```

But of course this does not work..Could you provide me any hints? It feels strange to copy the code of the two methods and just change one part.

Comment: Most probably, you should only change the method signature like this: LoadCollection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @StasIvanov answer you are just missing the generic type parameter on your signature:

```
private void LoadCollection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection)
{
}
```

You can extend this to use a specific generic type if your classes have a common interface or class, for example:

```
private void LoadCollection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection) where T : IMarkDeleted
{
    //you can then use common properties within the method
    observableCollection.Where(x => !x.MarkedAsDeleted);
}
```

Furthermore, if you plan on having additional generic methods you may benefit from having these in a class in which case you only need to include generic specification once at the class level and your methods won't need it:

```
public class ObservableCollectionHelper<T> where T : IEntity, IMarkDeleted
{
    public static T NewItem()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    private void LoadCollection(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection)
    {
    }

    private void DeleteCollection(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your method signature like this (adding  generic type parameter to it):

```
private void LoadCollection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection)
{

}
```

It should work, because it will infer the  generic argument from the collection you are passing to the method. But of course, the code inside this method should make no assumptions about type T (unless you specify generic type constraints using the *where* keyword)

Comment: Thank you! That was very embarrassing for me! have to check out for the where keyword next because like you said, I am now stuck how to handle the BarcodeCollection.Add(new Barcode(dr)) part..

Comment: You can add the new keyword as a generic type constraint. That way you can initialize a new instance of T with the new keyword inside your generic function. But to make this happen, you need an empty contructor. Maybe you can set the datarow after calling new T();